# How to deallocate memory without using free() in c

Tags: c

```
int main(void)
{
    int *a = malloc(10);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I free the memory without using `free()`?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use `free()`?

Comment: Because the professor asked you?

Comment: _How can I add numbers without using `+`?_

Comment: @SLaks: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4679556/922184

Comment: I'm with Dan, why don't you want to free()?

Comment: The memory is freed when your program exits...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the manpage:

The realloc() function changes the size of the memory block pointed to by ptr to size bytes.  The contents will be unchanged in the range from the start of the region
   up  to the minimum of the old and new sizes.  If the new size is larger than the old size, the added memory will not be initialized. If ptr is NULL, then the call is
   equivalent to malloc(size), for all values of size; if size is equal to zero, and ptr is not NULL, then the call is equivalent to free(ptr).  Unless ptr is  NULL,  it
   must have been returned by an earlier call to malloc(), calloc() or realloc().  If the area pointed to was moved, a free(ptr) is done.

So, you need to call realloc() with size as 0.

```
realloc(a, 0);
```

Comment: +1, this reminds me a famous thread with U. D. on glibc bugzilla http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12547

Answer (score -1):

`alloca()` allocates memory on the stack frame of the caller, which is freed upon return. This function's behavior isn't portable and the man page itself says not to use it.

Comment: That doesn't really answer his question, you are suggesting a way to avoid allocating, he wants to free.

Comment: It's kind of a trick question, isn't it? `alloca()` doesn't avoid allocating; it avoids the heap.